# ¿Cómo lograr que pida el nombre del archivo de texto en lenguaje c?

Tags: c, archivo

Muy buenos días, estoy intentando crear un programa que realice varias funciones, en este caso que se puedan crear múltiples archivos de texto. por lo que quiero que en cada una de las funciones del programa pidan el nombre del archivo a abrir.

Mi problema es que logre que se puedan crear y llenar los datos de los archivos pero no he podido avanzar en lo que es la lectura del archivo así que mi pregunta seria ¿Qué me esta fallando?

específicamente en esta parte del código, en si quiero que el programa me pida el nombre del archivo, que abra el archivo y que muestre todos los datos que se hayan insertado.

```
void imprimir(void)
{
    int i;
    strcpy(ruta, "C:\\prueba\\");
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(ruta, nombre);
        strcat(ruta, ".txt");

      archivo=fopen(ruta,"rb");
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
           fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
           printf("Clave del libro:%d\n", libros[i].clave);
           printf("Titulo del libro:%s\n", libros[i].titulo);
           printf("Autor del libro: %s\n", libros[i].autor);
           printf("Editorial del libro: %s\n", libros[i].editorial);
           printf("Editado en: %d\n", libros[i].anio);
           printf("\n\n");
      }
      fclose(archivo);
  }
```

adjunto mi codigo completo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define n 4


FILE *archivo;

struct libro
{
int clave;
char titulo[50];
char autor[30];
char editorial[30];
int anio;
}libros[n];

char nombre [30];
char ruta [60];

void llenar(void);
void imprimir(void);
void busqueda_cansada(void);
void busqueda_con_centinela(void);
void busqueda_binaria(void);

void modificar(void);     
void eliminar(void);
void menu(void);
void burbuja_clave(void);
void burbuja_anio(void);


void main()
{

 int opcion;

do
{
  
  menu();
  scanf("%i", &opcion);
  switch(opcion)
  {
   case 1: llenar(); break;
   case 2: imprimir();getch(); break;
   case 3: busqueda_cansada();getch();break;
   case 4: busqueda_con_centinela();getch(); break;
   case 5: busqueda_binaria();getch(); break;
   case 6: burbuja_clave();getch(); break;
   case 7: burbuja_anio();getch(); break;
   default: printf("No es una opcion valida");
  }
  fflush(stdin);

}while(opcion!=8);

getch();
}


void menu(void)
{
   
    printf("\n1) Crear archivo\n");
    printf("2) Leer archivo\n");
    printf("3) Busqueda cansada\n");
   printf("4) Busqueda con centinela\n");
    printf("5) Busqueda binaria\n");
    printf("6) Ordenamiento con Burbuja por clave\n");
   printf("7) Ordenamiento con Burbuja por año\n");
   printf("8) Salir\n");
   printf("\t\t\tOpcion: ");
}

void llenar(void)
{
     int i;
     
        getchar();
        strcpy(ruta, "C:\\prueba\\");
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(ruta, nombre);
        strcat(ruta, ".txt");
                
        archivo=fopen(ruta, "wb");
    
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
           printf("Clave del libro: \n");
           scanf("%d", &libros[i].clave);
           fflush(stdin);
           getchar();
           printf("Titulo del libro: \n");
           gets(libros[i].titulo);
           printf("Autor del libro: \n");
           gets(libros[i].autor);
           printf("Editorial del libro: \n");
           gets(libros[i].editorial);
           printf("Editado en: \n");
           scanf("%d", &libros[i].anio);
           fwrite(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);
        }fclose(archivo);
}

void imprimir(void)
{
    int i;
    strcpy(ruta, "C:\\prueba\\");
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(ruta, nombre);
        strcat(ruta, ".txt");
    
      archivo=fopen(ruta,"rb");
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
           fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
           printf("Clave del libro:%d\n", libros[i].clave);
           printf("Titulo del libro:%s\n", libros[i].titulo);
           printf("Autor del libro: %s\n", libros[i].autor);
           printf("Editorial del libro: %s\n", libros[i].editorial);
           printf("Editado en: %d\n", libros[i].anio);
           printf("\n\n");
      }
      fclose(archivo);
  }



void busqueda_cansada(void)
{
  int i,valor;
        printf("Da una clave a buscar:");
      scanf("%d", &valor);
      archivo=fopen("C:\\prueba\\libros.bin","rb");
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
        if(valor==libros[i].clave)
            printf("\nEncontrado\n");
        else
            printf("\nNo Encontrado\n");
      }
       fclose(archivo);
}

void busqueda_con_centinela(void)
{
   int i,valor, encontro=-1, pos;
        printf("Da una clave a buscar:");
      scanf("%d", &valor);
      archivo=fopen("C:\\prueba\\libros.bin","rb");

      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
        if(valor==libros[i].clave)
            {
            encontro=1; 
            pos=i;
         }
      }
       fclose(archivo);


       if(encontro==1)
       {
        printf("\n******************Encontrado en la posicion %d***************\n", pos);
         printf("Clave del libro:%d\n", libros[pos].clave);
         printf("Titulo del libro:%s\n", libros[pos].titulo);
         printf("Autor del libro: %s\n", libros[pos].autor);
         printf("Editorial del libro: %s\n", libros[pos].editorial);
         printf("Editado en: %d\n", libros[pos].anio);
         printf("\n\n");
       }
       else
        printf("\nNo Encontrado\n");
}

void busqueda_binaria(void)
{
int i, clave, inf=0, sup=n, mitad;
char band='F';
archivo=fopen("C:\\prueba\\libros.bin", "rb");
printf("\nProporciona la clave del libro a buscar: ");
scanf("%i", &clave);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);

while(inf<=sup) 
{
mitad=(inf+sup)/2;
if(libros[mitad].clave==clave)
    band='V';
break;
}


if(libros[mitad].clave>clave)
{
sup=mitad;
mitad=(inf+sup)/2;
}

if(libros[mitad].clave<clave)
{
inf=mitad;
mitad=(inf+sup)/2;
}

}

if(band=='V')
{
printf("\n\nClave del libro: %i", libros[mitad].clave);
printf("\nTitulo del libro: %s", libros[mitad].titulo);
printf("\nAutor del libro: %s", libros[mitad].autor);
printf("\nEditorial del libro: %s", libros[mitad].editorial);
printf("\nEditado en: %i\n", libros[mitad].anio);
}
else
    if(band=='F')
    {
        printf("\n\nNo se encuentra");
    }
fclose(archivo);
  }

void burbuja_clave(void)
{
    int temp, x, y, i;
     char temp_titulo[50];
        char temp_autor[30];
        char temp_editorial[30];
        int temp_anio;

   
    archivo=fopen("C:\\prueba\\libros.bin","rb");
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
           fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
      }
      fclose(archivo);

   


       for ( x=0; x<n; x++)
     {
        for ( y=0; y<n; y++)
      {
        if(libros[x].clave < libros[y].clave)
        {
            temp= libros[x].clave;
            libros[x].clave=libros[y].clave;
            libros[y].clave=temp;

            strcpy(temp_titulo, libros[x].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[x].titulo,libros[y].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[y].titulo,temp_titulo);

            strcpy(temp_autor,libros[x].autor);
            strcpy(libros[x].autor,libros[y].autor);
            strcpy(libros[y].autor,temp_autor);

            strcpy(temp_editorial,libros[x].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[x].editorial,libros[y].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[y].editorial,temp_editorial);

            temp_anio=libros[x].anio;
            libros[x].anio=libros[y].anio;
            libros[y].anio=temp_anio;
        }
      }
      }

     archivo=fopen("C:\\prueba\\libros.bin","wb");
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
         fwrite(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);
        }fclose(archivo);


      getch();

}

void burbuja_anio(void)
{
    int temp, x, y, i;
     char temp_titulo[50];
        char temp_autor[30];
        char temp_editorial[30];
        int temp_anio;

   
    archivo=fopen("C:\\prueba\\libros.bin","rb");
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
           fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
      }
      fclose(archivo);

   


       for ( x=0; x<n; x++)
     {
        for ( y=0; y<n; y++)
      {
        if(libros[x].anio < libros[y].anio)
        {
            temp= libros[x].clave;
            libros[x].clave=libros[y].clave;
            libros[y].clave=temp;

            strcpy(temp_titulo, libros[x].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[x].titulo,libros[y].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[y].titulo,temp_titulo);

            strcpy(temp_autor,libros[x].autor);
            strcpy(libros[x].autor,libros[y].autor);
            strcpy(libros[y].autor,temp_autor);

            strcpy(temp_editorial,libros[x].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[x].editorial,libros[y].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[y].editorial,temp_editorial);


            temp_anio=libros[x].anio;
            libros[x].anio=libros[y].anio;
            libros[y].anio=temp_anio;
        }
      }
      }

     archivo=fopen("C:\\prueba\\libros.bin","wb");
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
         fwrite(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);
        }fclose(archivo);


      getch();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para acceder o crear un fichero con un nombre en especifico seria asi, puedes omitir la parte de extension si es que el usuario dara el nombre del fichero mas su extesion:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[30];
    char extension[]=".txt";
    scanf("%s",a);
    strcat(a,extension);
    FILE *arc;
    arc=fopen(a,"w");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estuve viendo tu código, imagino que lo que quieres es algo parecido a esto.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define n 4


FILE *archivo;

struct libro
{
int clave;
char titulo[50];
char autor[30];
char editorial[30];
int anio;
}libros[n];


void llenar(void);
void imprimir(void);
void busqueda_cansada(void);
void busqueda_con_centinela(void);
void busqueda_binaria(void);

void modificar(void);     
void eliminar(void);
void menu(void);
void burbuja_clave(void);
void burbuja_anio(void);


void main()
{

 int opcion;

do
{
  
  menu();
  scanf("%i", &opcion);
  switch(opcion)
  {
   case 1: llenar(); break;
   case 2: imprimir();getch(); break;
   case 3: busqueda_cansada();getch();break;
   case 4: busqueda_con_centinela();getch(); break;
   case 5: busqueda_binaria();getch(); break;
   case 6: burbuja_clave();getch(); break;
   case 7: burbuja_anio();getch(); break;
   default: printf("No es una opcion valida");
  }
  fflush(stdin);

}while(opcion!=8);

getch();
}


void menu(void)
{
   
    printf("\n1) Crear archivo\n");
    printf("2) Leer archivo\n");
    printf("3) Busqueda cansada\n");
   printf("4) Busqueda con centinela\n");
    printf("5) Busqueda binaria\n");
    printf("6) Ordenamiento con Burbuja por clave\n");
   printf("7) Ordenamiento con Burbuja por año\n");
   printf("8) Salir\n");
   printf("\t\t\tOpcion: ");
}

void llenar(void)
{
    int i;
     char nombre [30];
        getchar();
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(nombre, ".txt");
        archivo=fopen(nombre, "wb");
    
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
           printf("Clave del libro: \n");
           scanf("%d", &libros[i].clave);
           fflush(stdin);
           getchar();
           printf("Titulo del libro: \n");
           gets(libros[i].titulo);
           printf("Autor del libro: \n");
           gets(libros[i].autor);
           printf("Editorial del libro: \n");
           gets(libros[i].editorial);
           printf("Editado en: \n");
           scanf("%d", &libros[i].anio);
           fwrite(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);
        }fclose(archivo);
}

void imprimir(void)
{
    int i;
     char nombre [30];
        getchar();
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(nombre, ".txt");
        archivo=fopen(nombre, "rb");
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
           fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
           printf("Clave del libro:%d\n", libros[i].clave);
           printf("Titulo del libro:%s\n", libros[i].titulo);
           printf("Autor del libro: %s\n", libros[i].autor);
           printf("Editorial del libro: %s\n", libros[i].editorial);
           printf("Editado en: %d\n", libros[i].anio);
           printf("\n\n");
      }
      fclose(archivo);
  }



void busqueda_cansada(void)
{
  int i,valor;
  char nombre [30];
     
        getchar();
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(nombre, ".txt");
        archivo=fopen(nombre, "rb"); 
        
        printf("Da una clave a buscar:");
      scanf("%d", &valor);
      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
        if(valor==libros[i].clave)
            printf("\nEncontrado\n");
        else
            printf("\nNo Encontrado\n");
      }
       fclose(archivo);
}

void busqueda_con_centinela(void)
{
   int i,valor, encontro=-1, pos;
  char nombre [30];
     
        getchar();
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(nombre, ".txt");
        archivo=fopen(nombre, "rb"); 
   
        printf("Da una clave a buscar:");
      scanf("%d", &valor);

      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
        fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
        if(valor==libros[i].clave)
            {
            encontro=1; 
            pos=i;
         }
      }
       fclose(archivo);


       if(encontro==1)
       {
        printf("\n******************Encontrado en la posicion %d***************\n", pos);
         printf("Clave del libro:%d\n", libros[pos].clave);
         printf("Titulo del libro:%s\n", libros[pos].titulo);
         printf("Autor del libro: %s\n", libros[pos].autor);
         printf("Editorial del libro: %s\n", libros[pos].editorial);
         printf("Editado en: %d\n", libros[pos].anio);
         printf("\n\n");
       }
       else
        printf("\nNo Encontrado\n");
}

void busqueda_binaria(void)
{
int i, clave, inf=0, sup=n, mitad;
char band='F';
char nombre [30];
     
        getchar();
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(nombre, ".txt");
        archivo=fopen(nombre, "rb"); 

printf("\nProporciona la clave del libro a buscar: ");
scanf("%i", &clave);

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);

while(inf<=sup) 
{
mitad=(inf+sup)/2;
if(libros[mitad].clave==clave)
    band='V';
break;
}


if(libros[mitad].clave>clave)
{
sup=mitad;
mitad=(inf+sup)/2;
}

if(libros[mitad].clave<clave)
{
inf=mitad;
mitad=(inf+sup)/2;
}

}

if(band=='V')
{
printf("\n\nClave del libro: %i", libros[mitad].clave);
printf("\nTitulo del libro: %s", libros[mitad].titulo);
printf("\nAutor del libro: %s", libros[mitad].autor);
printf("\nEditorial del libro: %s", libros[mitad].editorial);
printf("\nEditado en: %i\n", libros[mitad].anio);
}
else
    if(band=='F')
    {
        printf("\n\nNo se encuentra");
    }
fclose(archivo);
  }

void burbuja_clave(void)
{
    int temp, x, y, i;
     char temp_titulo[50];
        char temp_autor[30];
        char temp_editorial[30];
        int temp_anio;
        char nombre [30];
     
        getchar();
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(nombre, ".txt");
        archivo=fopen(nombre, "rb"); 



      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
           fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
      }
      fclose(archivo);

   


       for ( x=0; x<n; x++)
     {
        for ( y=0; y<n; y++)
      {
        if(libros[x].clave < libros[y].clave)
        {
            temp= libros[x].clave;
            libros[x].clave=libros[y].clave;
            libros[y].clave=temp;

            strcpy(temp_titulo, libros[x].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[x].titulo,libros[y].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[y].titulo,temp_titulo);

            strcpy(temp_autor,libros[x].autor);
            strcpy(libros[x].autor,libros[y].autor);
            strcpy(libros[y].autor,temp_autor);

            strcpy(temp_editorial,libros[x].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[x].editorial,libros[y].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[y].editorial,temp_editorial);

            temp_anio=libros[x].anio;
            libros[x].anio=libros[y].anio;
            libros[y].anio=temp_anio;
        }
      }
      }

    archivo=fopen(nombre, "wb"); 
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
         fwrite(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);
        }fclose(archivo);


     

}

void burbuja_anio(void)
{
    int temp, x, y, i;
     char temp_titulo[50];
        char temp_autor[30];
        char temp_editorial[30];
        int temp_anio;
        char nombre [30];
     
        getchar();
        printf("Da el nombre del achivo: ");
        gets(nombre);
        strcat(nombre, ".txt");
        archivo=fopen(nombre, "wb"); 

      for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
           fread(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1 , archivo);
      }
      fclose(archivo);

   


       for ( x=0; x<n; x++)
     {
        for ( y=0; y<n; y++)
      {
        if(libros[x].anio > libros[y].anio)
        {
            temp= libros[x].clave;
            libros[x].clave=libros[y].clave;
            libros[y].clave=temp;

            strcpy(temp_titulo, libros[x].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[x].titulo,libros[y].titulo);
            strcpy(libros[y].titulo,temp_titulo);

            strcpy(temp_autor,libros[x].autor);
            strcpy(libros[x].autor,libros[y].autor);
            strcpy(libros[y].autor,temp_autor);

            strcpy(temp_editorial,libros[x].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[x].editorial,libros[y].editorial);
            strcpy(libros[y].editorial,temp_editorial);
          

            temp_anio=libros[x].anio;
            libros[x].anio=libros[y].anio;
            libros[y].anio=temp_anio;
        }
      }
      }

     archivo=fopen(nombre, "wb"); 
     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
         fwrite(&libros[i], sizeof(struct libro), 1, archivo);
        }fclose(archivo);
        
        getch();

}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).